# Setting a responsive height to a container while vertically centering content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solve an issue where the height of a container should be responsive when someone minimizes the browser window. Content in that container should stay veritcally centered too.

Here's what I have so far in CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNZzoe

The container is the blue box which contains some text. The blue box should have the same height as the dummy image when adjusting the browser window size.

Thanks ahead for the help!

Code in CodePen:

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid_12 alpha omega" id="LLcontentCont">

    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <div class="LLrow" id="LLrow1">
      <div class="LLcontent">
        <div class="grid_4 LLFR alpha">
          <div class="LLtext">
            <h3>HEADER</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam hendrerit tristique sem, dictum ornare lectus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_8 omega">
          <a href="" title=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/868x500/00e1ff/000.gif&text=dummy+image" alt=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Row 1 -->

    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <div class="LLrow" id="LLrow2">
      <div class="LLcontent">
        <div class="grid_8 alpha">
          <a href="" title=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/868x500/00e1ff/000.gif&text=dummy+image" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 LLFL omega">
          <div class="LLtext">
            <h3>HEADER</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam hendrerit tristique sem, dictum ornare lectus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Row 2 -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

#LLcontentCont {width: 100%;}

#LLcontentCont,
.LLrow,
.grid_4,
.grid_8 {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.LLrow {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.LLcontent {
  min-width: 976px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.LLcontent .grid_4 {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0091ff;
  width: 26%;
}

.LLcontent .grid_8 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 72.3%;
}

.LLcontent .grid_8 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.LLtext {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all other display property and give `display: flex;` to `.LLcontent` and `.LLcontent .grid_4`. And `align-items: center;` to `.LLcontent .grid_4` will work for you.

Css:

```
.LLcontent {
  min-width: 976px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.LLcontent .grid_4 {
  background: #0091ff;
  width: 26%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.LLcontent .grid_8 {
  width: 72.3%;
}

.LLcontent .grid_8 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cgxrxao/)**